# What is a Vail word™

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Vail Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Vail Words™ | Not Vail Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| KNOTTED | TIED |
| ONLY | CHOICE |
| JUMP | LEAPED |
| TROOPS | SOLDIER |
| MARTYR | DIED |
| KEY | ENCODES |
| CONTACT | LIFT |
| QUOTE | AUTHOR |
| NATION | ENGLAND |
| DROP | THROUGH |
| WINDOW | ANDROID |
| WROTE | ARTICLE |
| TAGGER | FREEZE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Vail Words™,Not Vail Words™
KNOTTED,TIED
ONLY,CHOICE
JUMP,LEAPED
TROOPS,SOLDIER
MARTYR,DIED
KEY,ENCODES
CONTACT,LIFT
QUOTE,AUTHOR
NATION,ENGLAND
DROP,THROUGH
WINDOW,ANDROID
WROTE,ARTICLE
TAGGER,FREEZE
```

Hint:

> To find the answer, look at the...

Hint 2:

> ...**name** of the category.

Hint 3:

> **T** and **O** are good, **E** and **H** are bad.

Hint 4:

> Orders 45 and 46 are ready!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a VAIL word is one which, when written in

> MORSE CODE has more dashes than dots.

> T and O are good since they are written using dashes only (- and - - -)
>  E and H are bad since they are written using dots only (. and . . . .)

Here are some of the counts as examples:

> [image: examples]

This is called a VAIL word, as

> Aflred Vail was a collaborator in the invention of Morse code, along with Morse himself.